# Kafka consumer with React js

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I am developing a real-time data streaming app using Spring Boot(backend) and react.js(frontend). I have a Kafka producer through which I am producing messages to a specific topic and a consumer that is consuming messages from a specific topic. But I want to show the consumed message in the front end. How can I get the consumed data in the front end? Is there any way that I can consume data directly from the front end?

```
I am sending message to kafka like
public void sendMessage (@NotNull ElectionVotingArea votingArea){         Message<ElectionVotingArea>message = MessageBuilder                 
    .withPayload(votingArea)                 
    .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.TOPIC,topic.name())                 
    .build();         
    kafkaTemplate.send(message);         
    logger.info("message produced ->"+message.getPayload());     
}
```

and consuming data like

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "partyWiseVote",groupId = "votingArea")public void onMessage(ConsumerRecord<String, ElectionVotingArea> record) {
    ElectionVotingArea votingArea = record.value();
    logger.info("message Consumed -> "+votingArea);
}
```